# Hibernate 5 annotation org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, annotations

I am trying to integrate spring latest version with the latest version of hibernate. Everything is annotation based. I am getting the exception :-

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.example.model.Customer
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1447) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:678) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
```

I checked the other similar questions at StackOverflow, but none of then solutions provided worked for me. Here is the code:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringHibernateDemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SpringHibernateDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
         dataSource.setDriverClass((Class<? extends Driver>)Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"));
        //BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        //dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customerDB");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("welcome");
        return  dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory createSessionFactory() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Customer.class);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","update");

        configuration.setProperties(properties);


        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder standardServiceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
        standardServiceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        standardServiceRegistryBuilder.applySetting(Environment.DATASOURCE,dataSource());

        MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(standardServiceRegistryBuilder.build());

        //metadataSources.addPackage("");
        return metadataSources.getMetadataBuilder().build().buildSessionFactory();

        //return metadataSources.getMetadataBuilder().build().getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomerDao customerDao() {
        return  new CustomerDao();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(createSessionFactory());
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setFistName("Amar");
        customer.setLastName("Arya");
        customer.setEmail("amar@gmail.com");
        customerDao().saveCustomer(customer);
    }
}
```

The Model object is:-

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    //@GeneratorType()
    private int id;

    private String fistName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    public Customer(String fistName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.fistName = fistName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Customer() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFistName() {
        return fistName;
    }

    public void setFistName(String fistName) {
        this.fistName = fistName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

The DAO layer is

```
public class CustomerDao extends AbstractDao<Customer> {

    public void saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
        save(customer);
    }
}

@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractDao<E> {

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void save(E e) {
        saveEntity(e);
    }

    private void saveEntity(E e) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(e);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing 2 approaches to configure your session factory:

- the deprecated way using `Configuration` class
- the new way using `MetadataSources` and `ServiceRegistryBuilder`

Try to only use the new way with something like this :

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory createSessionFactory() throws ClassNotFoundException {

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","update");

    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder standardServiceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
    standardServiceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(properties);
    standardServiceRegistryBuilder.applySetting(Environment.DATASOURCE,dataSource());

    MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(standardServiceRegistryBuilder.build());
    metadataSources.addAnnotatedClass(Customer.class);
    return metadataSources.getMetadataBuilder().build().buildSessionFactory();
}
```

Comment: This works!!!! Thanks a lot. I do have another question. How do I add multiple files ? addPackage("packagename") doesnot seem to work.